# Problem using .splice() in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to extract subsets of 2D array using splice in Google App Script. A is the input array from which two arrays info[] and ttdata[] is being created. Following is the code:

```
function SpliceTest()
{
  var A = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6], 
  ["","","","1","",""],["","","","","2",""]]
  Logger.log(A)      
   var spliced = SpliceData(A)
  Logger.log(A)
}

function SpliceData(data)
{
  var info = []
  var ttdata = []
  for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
   {
     info[j] = data[j].splice(4, 2)
  }
  for(var j = 2; j < data.length; j++)
  {
     ttdata[j-2] = data[j].splice(0, 4)
   }
   return [info, ttdata]
 }
```

The issue is, executing the spliceData subroutine modifies the input array A, which I am not able to understand.

Below are the values of A before and after execution of SpliceData subroutine.

```
[19-01-25 11:28:05:493 CET] [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [, , , 1, , ], [, , , , 2, ]]
[19-01-25 11:28:05:494 CET] [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0], [, ], [2, ]]
```

Comment: What do you not understand? What is the expected output?

Comment: Probably you meant `slice` instead of `splice`. Splices are explicitly meant to graft something from one place onto another, e.g. "gene splicing".

Comment: I wish to extract 2 subsets of A and put them into the array info[] and ttdata[]. This part I achieved, but I also need the original A which is now lost. I do not understand this part why A is being modified.

Comment: Why not just make a copy of array A before you start.

Comment: I tried making copy of the array too. But the copy also gets modified after executing splice subroutine.

Comment: I tried .slice with a copy of A beforehand. Even that is modifying A as well as its copy.

Comment: @tehhowch slice would also mean cutting away from the original pie:)

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, as Tehhowch mentioned in the comment, you needed [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead of [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Furthermore, if you go through the documentation you will notice splice modifies the original array and slice makes a shallow copy of it.

```js
function SpliceTest()
{
  var Logger = console
  var A = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,5,6], 
  ["","","","1","",""],["","","","","2",""]]

   var spliced = SpliceData(A)
  Logger.log("Spliced Array:")
  Logger.log(spliced)
  Logger.log("Original Array A:")
  Logger.log(A)
}

function SpliceData(data)
{
  var info = []
  var ttdata = []
  for(var j = 0; j < 2; j++)
   {
     info[j] = data[j].slice(4)
  }
  for(var j = 2; j < data.length; j++)
  {
     ttdata[j-2] = data[j].slice(0, 4)
   }
   return [info, ttdata]
 }
 SpliceTest()
```

Note: I modified the code i.e. `var Logger = console`so that it can run as a code snippet here!

Comment: It seems slice() also modifies the array. Making a copy beforehand doesn't help either.

Comment: I am running the code snippet above and it doesn't modify the array A.

Comment: Also note the subtle change in the syntax between splice and slice!

Comment: @Partha Read about differences between a shallow copy and deep copy.

Comment: @Jack Brown, Tehhowch, Problem solved using slice().  Thanks for help.